# creating elements - most concise syntax?

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

Okay, I'm new to coffeescript but it has been really growing on me and I've just started on a new project with it. I love how succinct one can be and was trying to work out how to concisely create html elements on the fly. The best I could come up with (using cs+jq) was:

```
div = $ "<div>", {
  class: "studio", id: "studio_#{v['id']}",
  text: "some text" }
```

However for longer lines if I want to avoid lint warning (and line length is one I stick to) I've found it necessary to wrap at the first curly brace. So my question is - is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is, just plain jQuery without the cofeecrap -> `var div = $('<div />', {'class':'studio', id:'studio_#{v["id"]}'}), test: 'some text'});`

Comment: Or `div = $ "<div class='studio' id='studio_#{v['id']}' text='some text' />"` if you just want the fewest characters. But most concise isn't necessarily the _best_ way to do something in terms of readability/maintainability. @adeneo - I don't know CoffeeScript, but I think you'd need to change the `#{...}` part into a string concatetation (I'm not sure if I got that part right in my version either).

Comment: The problem with just using a string is that on complex elements these can become VERY messy hence why I started to look at other ways to write these as concisely as possible. For simple elements though, its possibly preferable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In coffeescript, I like to do things this way:

```
$ "<div>",
  class: "studio"
  id: "studio_#{v['id']}"
  text: "some text"
```

I find it much more readable in the end :)

Comment: That is nicer; no need for the curly braces (doh!) or the commas! Thank you.